ServiceNow Angular.js portal widget and altering HTML template of embedded widgets
I'm working with ServiceNow angular.js portal widgets and in order to avoid cloning widgets I instead make my own and embed their widget into mine. And then I do all sorts of stuff to manipulate the embedded widget data.
Including altering the HTMl template of the embedded widget.
However, it seems like it stores it in cache, cause if I navigate to another page where the same widget is used as the one I embedded in the first one, the alterned HTML template is rendered. If I refresh it's back to normal again.
What could be going on here?
My Server Script is simple:
data.widget = $sp.getWidget('relevant_for_you', options);

And the client script is something like this:
let widgetsData = c.data.widget.data.widgetsData;

widgetsData.forEach(item => {
    
    // Proceed with cloning and modifying the template
    let thisWidgetTemplate = item.data.widgetData.template.slice(0);

    // Create a temp jQuery object from the HTML string
    let $tempDiv = $('<div>').html(thisWidgetTemplate);

    // Find the element with the class card-image-container
    let $contentContainer = $tempDiv.find('.content-card-container');

    if ($contentContainer.length > 0) {
        // Create a temporary element
        let $newElement = $('<div>', {
            class: 'arrow-container',
            text: item.data.widgetData.orderMessage
        });

        // Append the new element to the content container
        $contentContainer.append($newElement);

        // Update the template with the modified HTML
        thisWidgetTemplate = $tempDiv.html();

        // Ensure the template is only injected into the intended widget
        item.data.widgetData.template = thisWidgetTemplate;
    } 

});

What's weird though is that if I console.log the HTML template in the other widget on the other page, the arrow-container element isn't part of the template. So it's almost as if it's living specifically in cache or something.
The HTML template of my widget is pretty simple and straightforward
 <div class="{{c.options.sp_column}}">
    <div ng-class="{'negative-margin': options.negative_top_margin === 'true' && c.location.indexOf('$spd.do') === -1}">
      <sp-widget widget="data.widget"></sp-widget>
    </div>
 </div>


What does your HTML template look like?

The HTML template is inserted as a string in these widgets in ServiceNow. It's nothing special. I updated the initial post to include it

So that's what it dynamically embeds, but you mentioned that you've created a widget yourself right, so what do you have written in that HTML template? I assume it is using c.data.widget (ie: <sp-widget widget='c.data.widget'></sp-widget>). I'm more after something that'll allow us to recreate your widget in a PDI so we have a [mre] to play with and see the issue.

Aha, okay, updated the first post again :)

The problem arises when I navigate to a topic page, my template is used on the catalog items listed there, because they use the same html template as the cards in the relevant for you widget.
And if I refresh the topic page then the arrow-container is gone, and if I navigate back to the front page then it's gone there too.
Probably because the topics widget reset the html template

Thanks for the additional info. Also which version of SN are you running? (I noticed that your client script is using ES6, which the linter normally complains about, unless potentially you've written this in a scoped app with ES2021+ support or are using the Xandu version?)

This is Washington and it's in a custom scoped app where es12 is used

I could resort to good old dom manipulation to inject the html I want to add. But I thought I had found a foolproof way to edit html templates of embedded widgets :D
I can still use this method for most widgets, but if some are shared or include a ton of nested widgets then it might not be such a good idea

Do you have a PDI with this issue, I can't seem to reproduce it. But yeah, I think your guess about this behavior is correct. Interesting.

But yeah, not sure how much better this technique would be to using regarding DOM manipulation as you're still relying on the structure of the OOTB widget to apply your changes (eg: by relying on the content card container class .find('.content-card-container')). Potentially cloning the OOTB widget might be the easier option that would be less likely to break in future upgrades.
